# Is $\mathbb{Z}$ isomorphic to a direct subproduct of the family $\left\{ \mathbb{Z}_{n}\right\} _{n>1}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, abelian-groups

Is $\mathbb{Z}$ isomorphic to a direct subproduct of the family $\left\{ \mathbb{Z}_{n}\right\} _{n>1}$?

Comment: What do you mean by "subproduct"?

Comment: I think they are one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming that $\mathbb Z_n$ means $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$.  I'm also assuming that "subproduct" means "subgroup of the product".  If this is the case then yes, the subgroup generated by $(1, 1, \ldots) \in \prod_{n > 1}\mathbb Z_n$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$.

To see that this is the case note that we can always define a homomorphism out of $\mathbb Z$ by picking an element $x$ and declaring $m \mapsto m\cdot x$.  So what we need is for this to be injective.  When $x = (1, 1, \ldots)$ we have $m\cdot x = (m, m, \ldots)$ and if $m \neq 0$ then the looking at the $|m| + 1$ coordinate gives $m\cdot x \neq 0$.  Another way to see this: if $p$ is prime then the coordinate of $(m, m, \ldots)$ corresponding to $\mathbb Z_p$ is zero if and only if $p$ divides $m$.  So if $m\cdot x = (0, 0, \ldots)$ then every prime divides $m$, so $m$ must be $0$.